# How I can identify that a process has multiple instances

Tags: linux, ps, nagios

In my case I have nagios server where nagios service is running. But when I run `ps -ef | grep nagios`, I can see:

```
nagios    3361 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3363 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3364 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3368 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3374 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3382 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3384 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3389 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3393 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3397 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3404 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3408 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3414 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
nagios    3416 13524  0 15:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

So is that instances of nagios process.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pgrep. See `man pgrep`

```
    $pgrep nagios                 #list all the process ids
```

for counting:

```
    $pgrep nagios | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pidof. Check out `man pidof` or `info pidof`. For example, running it on my current setup presents the following:

```
pidof chrome
3946 3202 3194 3175 3154 3137 3114 3103 3077 3024 3019 3012 3005 2998
```

As @Ijaz has suggested, you could also get the count by:

```
pidof chrome | wc -l
14
```